# OAuth2 Provider gem for non-rails, non-mongo apps?

Tags: ruby, oauth-2.0, omniauth

I need to add OAuth2 authentication to a Sinatra-based API.  No ActiveRecord, no MongoDB... but DataMapper.

Does anybody know what gems I can use to achieve this?  I added rack-oauth2-server, but it depends on Mongo.  I'm trying to understand [rack-oauth2](https://github.com/nov/rack-oauth2), but there is practically no documentation and I can't see how this is supposed to integrate in a real application that *provides* oauth authentication.  Any well-documented gems out there?  (Not Rails gems).

omniauth-oauth2 looked like it would work, but again, there's basically no documentation on how to integrate it.  Links to articles that outline integration with these gems would also be useful.

I've been searching all day and just keep going around in circles.  I'm sure this is a solved problem.

Answer (score 0):

Why you didn't look at http://rubydoc.info/gems/oauth2/0.7.1/frames?

Comment: It seems to only be a client.  I need a provider (i.e. the bit that you run on the server in order for other parties to connect to *you* via OAuth).

Comment: Yes it is. For provider you have to have a persistent storage anyway - you have access to one using Sinatra?

Comment: Yeah I have a Postgres DB and DataMapper.

Comment: There is doc for omniauth-oauth2 - but you have to start from different point : [https://github.com/intridea/omniauth](https://github.com/intridea/omniauth) : in intro you'll find how to set up server. Then OAuth2 in their implementation is a Strategy in sense of [http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Strategy_pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Strategy_pattern).